# How to open an .as file in Flash CC and jump to a particular line / column?

Tags: flash, command-line, argument-passing, flash-ide

So if, for instance, I wanted to open an .as file in Notepad ++ with the cursor lined up at the 15th character of the 10th line, the command might look like this:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe filename.as -n10 -c15

What's the equivalent for the Flash IDE?

---

*(I know this is kind of only tangentially a programming question, but this seemed like the most applicable place for it.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe has improved the Flash IDE with Flash CC but it's still not a text editor or a fully featured code editor. So no it can't do that. Many people using Flash IDE, code on the side with a free code editor like FLashDevelop to avoid using the Flash IDE for that purpose.

Comment: aw, "can't be done" isn't the answer I wanted, but it sounds like that's the answer I get. thanks!